# Not able to use python-nvd3

Tags: python, d3.js, flask

I am completely new to web development and this is my first web app using Python and Flask.
For plotting purposes I am using python-nvd3.
I followed the instructions here : http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#documentation

I am using the sample code they have provided for the pie-chart (in the link above). I installed python-nvd3 (I am able to import). When I run my python application it reloads the Flask server(localhost) and I am able to view the HTML page in Firefox, however the plot is absent. When I go to Tools->Web Developer->Web Console I can see the page source. It shows the following error:

`[14:08:38.311] ReferenceError: nv is not defined @ http://localhost:5000/view_plot:20`

By default python-nvd3 adds the following scripts in the auto-generated HTML page:

`<link media="all" href="./bower_components/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

`<script src="./bower_components/d3/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="./bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

However I get a 404 error when I try to access these links(why are they relative paths?). I think this is the cause for the error.
Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: Okay, it works when I manually add the correct full paths e.g. https://raw.github.com/novus/nvd3/master/lib/d3.v2.min.js.

Comment: Hi there. I have a similar problem. Did you manually correct the paths in your saved HTML pages or did you correct the way python-nvd3 generates them?

Comment: Yes, I manually added the correct paths

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting called assets_directory directory holding the assets (./bower_components/)
https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/blob/master/nvd3/NVD3Chart.py#L78

You can use this to point to a different asset directory, the one you will use with Flask.

Alternative you can also change this to use a CDN